# Quoting Windows batch arguments that may end in backslash

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to quote arbitrary arguments in a Windows 10 batch file, and I'm having problems when they end in a backslash.

Let's say I want to call Robocopy to copy `*.foo` files from `A:\` to `B:\` like this:

```
robocopy A:\ B:\ *.foo
```

But really I'm getting `A:\` as an argument (let's say I use `%~1`, and I don't know if it contains spaces, so I quote it:

```
robocopy "%SOURCE%" B:\ *.foo
```

Unfortunately if `%SOURCE%` ends with a backslash, the last `\` is considered an escape character, escaping `"`.

```
robocopy "A:\" B:\ *.foo
```

So Windows thinks the first argument is `"A:" B:\ *.foo`.

How can I turn off interpretation of `\"` as an escape sequence?

Comment: But \ isn't an escape character in batch... is this some weird functionality of robocopy that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @SomethingDark Yes, __ROBOCOPY__ is different in comparison to most other commands and interprets a trailing backslash as escape character. Documentation of [robocopy on ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) warns about a special handling of a trailing backslash by __ROBOCOPY__.

Comment: @SomethingDark __REG__ is another command which interprets a trailing backslash as an escape character as it can be seen by running twice `reg add "HKCU\Environment" /v MyRegTest /t REG_SZ /d "%TEMP%\" /f`. The user is prompted on second run although there is `/f` at end. But run `reg query "HKCU\Environment" /v MyRegTest` and it can be seen what was really added on first run. Run last `reg delete "HKCU\Environment" /v MyRegTest /f` to remove the added __user__ environment variable with a value ending with `" /f` not expected by most users.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple! You need to escape the escape character! When you use `\\` instead of `\`, the first backslash escapes the second, and nothing further is escaped.

So, while running your command, you should use this:

```
<command> "this\is\a\path\\" "\this\is\another\path\\"
```

It is also worth nothing that `robocopy` works even if you don't end the paths with backslashes. So you can also totally just use this:

```
robocopy "this\is\a\path" "this\is\another\path" <args>
```

If you don't know whether or not the path ends with a backslash (for example if you're taking it from a user), you can use this command to escape all backslashes in the path:

```
%SOURCE%=%SOURCE:\=\\%
```

After which you can run robocopy normally using `%SOURCE%` as an argument, even if it ends with a backslash!

Comment: I'm running robocopy from within a batch file. I don't want the user of the batch file to need to escape things on the command line.

Comment: Even though robocopy works if you don't end the paths without backslashes, `B:\ ` and `B:` are two very different things; the second is relative to the current directory.

Comment: @GarretWilson See the last solution, `%SOURCE%=%SOURCE:\=\\%` is what you need

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a batch file like this commented one:

```
@echo off
if not exist %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe goto BatchHelp
if "%~1" == ""   goto BatchHelp
if "%~1" == "/?" goto BatchHelp
if "%~2" == ""   goto BatchHelp

call :CleanPath SOURCE %1
call :CleanPath DESTINATION %2

%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SOURCE%" "%DESTINATION%" *.foo

rem Delete the used environment variables.
set "SOURCE="
set "DESTINATION="

rem Avoid a fall through to the subroutine CleanPath.
exit /B

rem The subroutine CleanPath must be called with two arguments.
rem The first one must be the environment variable which should hold the
rem cleaned folder path for usage with ROBOCOPY. The second argument must
rem be the folder path which should be cleaned for usage with ROBOCOPY.

:CleanPath
rem Get full absolute path of folder path. This reduces a lot of variants
rem which could occur on batch file called with various relative paths.
set "FolderPath=%~f2"

rem Does the folder path not end with a backslash?
if not "%FolderPath:~-1%" == "\" goto HavePath

rem Does the folder path have just three characters and is ending with
rem a colon and a backslash? Yes, append an escaping backslash at end.
rem Otherwise the folder path of a folder not being the root folder
rem of a drive ends with a backslash which must be removed to get
rem the folder path correct interpreted by ROBOCOPY.
if "%FolderPath:~1%" == ":\" (
    set "FolderPath=%FolderPath%\"
) else (
    set "FolderPath=%FolderPath:~0,-1%"
)

:HavePath
set "%~1=%FolderPath%"
set "FolderPath="

rem Return to calling routine.
goto :EOF


:BatchHelp
cls
echo Usage: %~nx0 source destination
echo(
echo        source ... source directory
echo   destination ... destination directory
echo(
echo This batch file requires ROBOCOPY in Windows system directory.
echo(
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`